# How to detect and prevent spawning failing Unicorn workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

**Situation:** I am using Rails + Unicorn, deploying with Capistrano. Sometimes Rails app fails to start in production mode (though it is not the real production, but a staging env). This usually happens due to errors in deploy scripts or configuration (thus usually not detectable by tests). When this happens, unicorn master process kills the worker that failed and spawns a new one, which also fails and so on and so forth. During all that time unicorn consumes lots of CPU and pollutes logs with the same message.

**Manual way (not good):** Go to your home page to see if it works. Look at the `htop`. Tail the logs. Kill unicorn manually. *Cons:* easy to forget. Logs are polluted, CPU is loaded while you are reacting.

**Another solution:** Use unicorn's `preload_app true`. This will cause master process to fail fast. *Cons:* higher memory consumption in happy scenario.

**Best practice:** - ???

Is there any way to cleverly detect that unicorn master uselessly tries to spawn failing children and stop it?

Answer (score 2):

You have something like "unicorn start" in your Capistrano script right? Make your Capistrano script ping Unicorn right after invoking that command. If Unicorn does not return an expected response within a timeout, then you know that something went wrong, and you can choose to rollback the deploy or performing some other action.

As for how to ping Unicorn, that depends. If you have Unicorn listening on a TCP socket then you can use curl. If you have Unicorn listening on a Unix domain socket then you have to write a little script that connects to it, like this:

```
require 'socket'
sock = UNIXSocket.new('/path-to-unicorn.sock')
sock.write("HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n")
sock.write("Host: www.foo.com\r\n")
sock.write("Connection: close\r\n")
sock.write("\r\n")
if sock.read !~ /something/
  exit 1
end
```

But it sounds like [Phusion Passenger Enterprise](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise) solves your problem beautifully. It has this feature called "deployment error resistance". When you deploy a new version and Phusion Passenger detects that it cannot spawn any processes for your new codebase, it will stop trying to spawn your new version and keep the processes for the old versions around indefinitely, until you manually give the signal that it's okay to spawn processes for the new version. In the mean time it will log all errors into the log file so that you can analyze the problem.

Comment: Automating "ping & kill" is a good solution, probably `monit` could do it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest brushing off your bash skills. The functionality you need is already in Unicorn as it leverages the Unix-y master/worker process.

You need a init.d script. Or at the very least godrb or monit. I recommend the init.d script route AND monitoring. Its more complex, but it can more easily be leveraged by your monitoring software and also gives you an automatic start on reboot.

The gist of it is:

1. Send the USR2 signal to the unicorn master process, this will fork the master process.
2. Then send the WINCH to the old master process that gets created, this will kill each worker.
3. Then you can send the old master process the  QUIT signal.

[Unicorn Signals](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html)

This will spin up a new master process running the new code and label the old one as (old). If it fails the old one should be returned to its prior state and you shouldn't suffer an outage, just a restart error. This is the beauty of unicorn. You can almost get instantaneous deploys of your code.

I'm using a lot of hedge words because I did this work on my apps over a year ago so there are a lot of cobwebs upstairs. Hope this helps!

This is by no mean a **correct** script. Its a good starting point though ... feel free to update the gist if you can improve upon it! :-)

[Example Unicorn Control Script](https://gist.github.com/3977588)

Comment: Many thanks for you answer. I am using init.d script that is in unicorn's examples. My main problem is around this: `If it fails the old one should be returned to its prior state` How to detect that the workers of the new master are failing, when it tries to respawn them again and again? Now I think there is no solution for this internal for unicorn, because it is its feature to recreate failing workers. It cannot differ an incidentally failed worker that *needs* to be replaced in order to continue providing the service, and a worker that failed to start because of the bug in the application.

Comment: Or you suggest to do it with monit?

Comment: IIRC the new master will die and the old one will be returned to be the master process. So you'd see no PID change on the unicorn master after a restart, also I think it writes to STDERR. If you have a race condition in your workers then unicorn master should fail to start. Or if it does start you'll see the signs of a race condition. The warning sign I usually see for this type of race condition is unicorn starts consuming large amounts of CPU percentage. This part can be caught with monitoring. godrb is fairly easy to play with so you may want to start there and set a CPU limit. :-)

Comment: also make sure you have log paths set in your unicorn config file. This way you'll see the errors as they occur.

Comment: Seems you are talking about different use case. If you have a rails app with an error is initializers, the master will not die, because it is not loading the app. It will spawn a worker, the worker will start an app, and fail, and master will spawn new worker, and so on, until I kill it manually. And yes, I do look at the logs, and at CPU load, as I said it the question, but got tired of checking it manually, so monitoring is probably the solution.

Comment: update FWIW: the specific use case I was referring to was if you have a running unicorn master and you're doing a "hot code" swap. i.e. with a Capistrano deploy. If the new unicorn master fails to start,  the old master will stay as the current master.  So it will essentially look like your changes are never being applied. Yet if you check the unicorn error log you should see the failures of the new unicorn master trying to start. :)